# isScrolledIntoView function wont remove class fixed of navigation bar

Tags: jquery

*I have this function for number counter, to start counting when is on screen, and that is working, but when i scroll and counter starts and when i go back jquery for removing class fixed of navigation wont work, and nav is stick on top of screen. When i erase this code for scroll, sticky navigation working just fine.*

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        var $window = $(window);

        var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

        var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if (isScrolledIntoView('#counter')) {
            $('.number-count').countTo();
            $(window).off('scroll');
        }
    });
```

*And this is jquery code for sticky navigation*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var navOffset = $(".nav").offset().top;
                $(".nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
                $(".nav-placeholder").height($(".nav").outerHeight());

            $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
                $(".nav").addClass("fixed");
            }   else {
                    $(".nav").removeClass("fixed");
                } 
            });
        });
```

*and here is youtube link for you to see problem if i didn explain it well*

https://youtu.be/_aX0dWl6ZfQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your `$(window).off('scroll')` line should only remove the handler it is contained in. Try accepting the event in the handler and passing that to .off:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    if (isScrolledIntoView('#counter')) {
        $('.number-count').countTo();
        $(window).off(e);
    }
});
```

That way you don't also remove the handler for your sticky header

Comment: Thanks man, that worked! I am still learning javascript, so sometimes i cant see even smallest mistakes. :)

Comment: Glad I could help, be sure to mark answers as accepted, or people will stop answering your questions ;)